# Property 'default' does not exist on type 'typeof firebase'. Error

Tags: typescript, firebase-realtime-database, progressive-web-apps

I am doing connection with firebase from pwa-starter-kit-template-typescript project and getting this error:

> ***Property 'default' does not exist on type 'typeof firebase'. ts(2339)***

If I do not use default, it gives error `firebase.auth() does not exist`.

I am using firebase verison 7.2.0. firebase is installed correctly.

That is my code.

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

import  'firebase/auth';

formValidation()
{

var emailid = this.shadowRoot?this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#myemail") as TextElement:null;

var pwd = this.shadowRoot?this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#mypassword") as TextElement:null;
var defaultauth= firebase.default.auth();
if(emailid!=null && pwd!=null){
  //this.defaultauth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(emailid.value, pwd.value).catch(function(error: { code: any; message: any; }){
  defaultauth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailid.value, pwd.value)
  .catch(function(error: { code: any; message: any; }){
    console.log(error.code);
    console.log(error.message);
  });
}
```

}

Comment: Not sure how to help without seeing 
code.

Comment: ok i am posting the code also.

Comment: Show the import of firebase

Comment: I added now. you can check......

Comment: yes its already true....

Comment: You need to write `import firebase from 'firebase';` There is no `default` export and the interop doesn't create one on the namespace import.

Comment: import firebase from 'firebase'; does not work. i already tried it. when I try my code in console, it shows firebase.default exists but firebase.auth() does not exist.

Comment: which version of firebase should i use?

Answer (score 0):

As Per firebase type definitions firebase does not have default property.

please change it as var defaultauth= firebase.auth(); and try.

Comment: i already tried it. it gives error "firebase.auth() does not exist."

Comment: It seems to be an issue that occurs when you have both firebase and firebase-admin installed in the same package.please confirm that your are using firebase-amin.uninstall(npm uninstall firebase-admin) and then try .